# Android apk replace vs Update

Tags: android

I have an application already installed on the mobile, am trying to install the update version of it.

I placed the apk inside the data/data folder, using file manager at the path,am trying to install it -
it shows a dialog to replace but not upgarde (Signed with the same key-store and version code/version name has an incremental value).

Could someone explain me more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between installing and subsequently, updating, apps off Google Play. Applications installed via a File Manager, for instance, will always prompt you to *replace* and not *update* an application. Side-loading apps on devices directly, does not have that mechanism to update. This is true not only for your app, but for every app.

It does not matter how it was signed or even the increment of your app's version.

Comment: Does replacing - deletes the cache ?

Comment: @Sreeram: Yes. Everything from the /data/app/ will be replaced. However, anything stored on the Internal or External memory will remain.

Comment: If this is the scenario - What is the procedure for testing compatibility before release?

Comment: @Sreeram: Testing what compatibility? And if you are releasing your app on Google Play, you won't have to worry about it. Updates via Play will not delete any data.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade is only possible when you actually follow the installation procedure from Android Market. Else, it would just be a replace.